# Java - Advanced modal dialog

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog

I would like to create a **modal** input dialog with some textboxex/labels. It's supposed to something like "Add client dialog" with name, surname, etc..

I've been searching the net for almost an hour and nothing.. JOptionPane can't handle the task, JFrame has no ShowDialog method etc. How can I accomplish the task in Swing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JOptionPane can't handle the task,

As you've realized you can add any component to a JOptionPane, including a panel.

One problem is that focus will be placed on the buttons, not the panel.

You can check out [Dialog Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) for a simple solution to this problem.

Comment: Thank you. Focus is not really important for me (I'm only writing a simple JMS homework application, but maybe one day..).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a plain old JDialog. Make it modal and use its content pane for your widgets.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, it set me back on the right track, although the solution is different: JOptionPane can do it! JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,cd,"Title",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION); cd is an instance of a Panel with everything I need.